# Is there a getter/setter like functionality for class functions in python?

Tags: python, class, properties, alias

I'm working on a project where the people who will be using one of my class methods will expect to have the method have different names (since the users are coming from multiple different research areas). So ideally, I would like to have some way of "aliasing" the class method so it would work under different names, as well as, if one of the users changes the method for a specific name, that change would also be seen if the method was called from a different name.  For an example:

```
class GeneralClass:

   def foo(self, x):
       print('Hello', x)


   # Define aliases for the method
   bar = foo
   spam = foo
   eggs = foo

g = GeneralClass()
g.foo('world')  # Output: 'Hello world'
g.bar('world')  # Output: 'Hello world'

# Redefine one of the methods
g.bar = lambda x: print('Goodbye', x)

# This breaks the aliasing
g.foo('world')  # Output: 'Hello world'
g.bar('world')  # Output: 'Goodbye world'
```

I tried to define `foo` using the `@property` decorator and using a getter and setter:

```
class GeneralClassWithProperty:

    def _universal_name(self):
        print('Hello')

    @property
    def universal_name(self):
        return self._universal_name

    @universal_name.setter
    def universal_name(self, new_method):
        self._universal_name = new_method

   # Define aliases for the method
    foo = universal_name
    bar = universal_name
    spam = universal_name
    eggs = universal_name

g_property = GeneralClassWithProperty()
```

However, I've since learned that getters/setters are just for class *attributes*, so you cannot pass in variables to the getter function. Thus if you call `g_property.foo('test')` you get an error that the `_universal_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'`.  I confirmed this aliasing approach works if we don't require the getter to take in any parameters (proof below), so is there any way we can use getter/setters for class *methods*?  (Or, is there another way of getting this synchronized aliasing I'm looking for?)

(Also, please don't suggest "Just have your users use `universal_name`, since sadly that's out of the question.)  Thank you!

---

Proof of getter/setter working for synchronized aliasing of class *attributes*

```
class GeneralClass:

    def _universal_name(self):
        print('Hello')

    @property
    def universal_name(self):
        return self._universal_name

    @universal_name.setter
    def universal_name(self, new_method):
        self._universal_name = new_method

   # Define aliases for the method
    foo = universal_name
    bar = universal_name
    spam = universal_name
    eggs = universal_name

g = GeneralClass()
g.foo()  # Output: 'Hello'
g.bar()  # Output: 'Hello'

# Redefine one of the methods
g.bar = lambda: print('Goodbye')

# This breaks the aliasing
g.foo()  # Output: 'Goodbye'
g.bar()  # Output: 'Goodbye'
```

Comment: A "getter" by nature **requires no arguments**, that is what makes it a *getter*

Comment: Also, fundamentally, `g.bar = lambda: print('Goodbye')` is **not redefining anything**. It is *shadowing* the method with an instance variable.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, why can't a getter be used to "get" a return value from a function (potentially with sanitizing the input beforehand).   Alas, I do see your point though. I guess my main question is "is there any other way to do the aliasing I need"?

Comment: You might be able to achieve something similar using `getattr` or `setattr`, but honestly the best solution is the one you don't want.

Comment: You don't even need a property here to begin with.

Comment: What you are describing is just a method that takes a parameter. Again, in any case, your claim does not seem to be true, see the output of me using your code with `property` to call a function with an argument, and also, see the code that doesn't use `property` to accomplish the same thing (it probably shouldn't use `property` since the `property` doesn't really do anything

Answer (score 0):

> However, I've since learned that getters/setters are just for class
> attributes, so you cannot pass in variables to the getter function.
> Thus if you call g_property.foo('test') you get an error that the
> _universal_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'.

No it doesn't. Here:

```
In [1]: class GeneralClass:
   ...:
   ...:     def _universal_name(self):
   ...:         print('Hello')
   ...:
   ...:     @property
   ...:     def universal_name(self):
   ...:         return self._universal_name
   ...:
   ...:     @universal_name.setter
   ...:     def universal_name(self, new_method):
   ...:         self._universal_name = new_method
   ...:
   ...:    # Define aliases for the method
   ...:     foo = universal_name
   ...:     bar = universal_name
   ...:     spam = universal_name
   ...:     eggs = universal_name
   ...:

In [2]: g = GeneralClass()

In [3]: g.foo()
Hello

In [4]: g.eggs()
Hello

In [5]: g.universal_name = lambda x: f"new {x}"

In [6]: g.foo('foo')
Out[6]: 'new foo'

In [7]: g.eggs('foo')
Out[7]: 'new foo'
```

But note, `property` isn't really doing anything here! Your propety getter/setters are completely pointless, the property should simply not exist:

You could just use:

```py
class GeneralClass:

   def universal(self):
       return f"Hello"

   def _universal_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
       return self.universal(*args, **kwargs)


   # Define aliases for the method
   foo = _universal_wrapper
   bar = _universal_wrapper
   spam = _universal_wrapper
   eggs = _universal_wrapper

g = GeneralClass()
print(g.foo())
g.universal = lambda x: f"goodbye, my dear {x}"
print(g.foo('Watson'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your task I would implement it like this:

```
class GenericClass:
    # Aliases tuple.
    # If this tuple will be defined in __init__ then AttributeError
    # will be raised, because __setattr__ is called before __init__
    # and self.names won't be defined.
    names = ("foo", "bar", "eggs")
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = self._wrapper
        self.bar = self._wrapper
        self.foobar = 1

    def _wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._inner(*args, **kwargs)

    def _inner(self, val):
        """
        The method that will be actually called.
        """
        print(f"Hello, {val}")

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        # This method is called when an attribute assignment is attempted.

        # Checking whether __setattr__ is called for one of the aliases.
        if name in self.names:
            # __dict__ is a dictionary or other mapping
            # object used to store an object’s (writable) attributes.
            # If the __dict__ doesn't contain alias name this
            # mean it is the first we set value to it (i.e. assignment
            # in __init__).
            # 
            # Setting value as is
            if name not in self.__dict__:
                self.__dict__[name] = value
            # If the alias name is in the __dict__ then update
            # '_inner' value.
            else:
                super().__setattr__("_inner", value)
        # If __setattr__ is called for non-alias name then
        # set value for this name as is.
        else:
            super().__setattr__(name, value)


In [46]: g = GenericClass()

In [47]: g.foo("world")
Hello, world

In [48]: g.bar("world")
Hello, world


In [49]: g.bar = lambda val: f"Goodbye, {val}"

In [50]: g.foo("world")
Out[50]: 'Goodbye, world'

In [51]: g.bar("world")
Out[51]: 'Goodbye, world'
```

[__setattr__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__), [__dict__](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__), [super()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)